# How to get text from unmanaged application to a c# application?

Tags: c#, c++, interop, com-interop

I have a 3rd party application, which creates several windows of which each has a textbox with text I want. I then want to use that information within my application, so I just need to obtain that information (possible trigger some commands back to it later on by pressing buttons)

The 3rd party application is un-managed C++.
My application is C# (.NET 4.0).

I have seen that you can do 'hooks' into other application but I'll be honest I am completely lost of which route to take and how to go about it.

Some advice would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest interop with an unmanaged C++ is via C++/CLI. If there's already a simple C wrapper then P/Invoke will be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for replying, know of any resources to show basic examples of grabbing text from a c++ app? Not done this kind of coding before

Comment: Looks complex and quite a learning curve, must be easier ways? My C++ is very limited so need reasons why your doing something etc. Is it possible to use something like PInvoke or Microsoft Detours? Maybe easier?

Comment: P/Invoke way is availabe only if you're calling plain C functions. And still you'd have to use all that marshalling functionality. It's not that complicated in fact, you don't need much of a C++ there, a simple wrapper library around your existing API.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if all this talk of managed code and unmanaged code and Interop isn't a red herring.  Are you able to interface with this other app at all or are you just going to have to use FindWindow to find that other app and then enumerate it's child windows till you find the text boxes you're after, then just call GetWindowText ?

Comment: Would have to use FindWindow and attempt to 'hook' up to the child windows much like this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/netwin32hooks.aspx but need for a textbox

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use COM interop. More here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

http://www.liensberger.it/web/blog/?p=323